# Fifer package : a problem downloading this package

Tags: r, error-handling, download, package

I have tried to download the package `fifer` using :

`install.packages`

`remotes::install_github("dustinfife/fifer")`

and I tried to dowload the latest version from the archive from the link below

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/fifer/

I downloaded it manually and extract it into the win-library file in R. but still didn't work. Would appreciate the help.

Comment: Could you show the error you get when using `remotes::install_github("dustinfife/fifer")` please? Do you have r-tools installed? https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: I have this `Downloading GitHub repo dustinfife/fifer@HEAD
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

 1: All                                       
 2: CRAN packages only                        
 3: None                                      
 4: digest     (0.6.29    -> 0.6.30   ) [CRAN]
 5: vctrs      (0.4.2     -> 0.5.1    ) [CRAN]
 6: ggplot2    (3.3.6     -> 3.4.0    ) [CRAN]
 7: xfun       (0.33      -> 0.35     ) [CRAN]
 8: jsonlite   (1.8.2     -> 1.8.3    ) [CRAN]`

Comment: And when I press 1, it is not downloaded

Comment: Press 3, just try to install `{fifer}`

Comment: Alternatively, in terminal, `git clone https://github.com/dustinfife/fifer.git`, R CMD build fifer,  R CMD INSTALL resulting tar.gz file.Useful to check `Description` that you have all needed (imports) packages installed prior.